# how to detect that return value from api is an empty object - angularjs call api

Tags: angularjs

this is my code:

```
getSetting() {
Loading.show();

const data = {
  vendorId: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("TOKEN_DATA_MAGIC")).user
    .vendorId,
};
this.api.getSetting(data).subscribe(
  (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    let res: any = data;
    if (res.setting != "not found") {
      const res: any = data;
      this.settingItem.Selling_Type = res.setting
        ? res.setting.Selling_Type
        : null;
      this.settingItem.Closing_hours = res.setting.Closing_hours;
      this.settingItem.Shipping = res.setting.Shipping;
      this.settingItem.Packaging = res.setting.Packaging;
      setTimeout(() => Loading.hide(), 1000);
      let msg = "تنظیمات دریافت شد";
      this.toastr.show(msg, "تنظیمات");
    }
  },
  (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    let errMsg = "خطا رح داد لاگ را نگاه کنید";
    let errFullMsg = "خطا در لاگ مرورگر";
    let errFullMessage = err.error.message ? err.error.message : errFullMsg;
    this.toastr.success(errFullMessage, errMsg);
  }
);
}
```

sometimes this returned object is: {}

and when i seek in console the value is {}

how can i detect it? when this value is an empty object

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys()`

```
if(Object.keys(obj).length === 0) { //Object is empty }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `object.entries() function`, Its used like this

```
Object.entries(objectToCheck)
```

If it returns an empty array, means it is empty ( returning empty array means the object does not have any enumerable property).

```
Object.entries(objectToCheck).length === 0
```

then do your required set of tasks.

For checking if object is really an object you can check if its constructor is the `Object` object like below

```
objectToCheck.constructor === Object
```